# How to setup tunnel/vxlan using "ip encap" for ipv6 on Linux?

Tags: linux-networking, ipv6, tunnel, vxlan

Using [light-weight tunnels](https://serverfault.com/questions/985656/linux-lightweight-tunnels) allows the same (tunnel)device to be used for many destinations (among other things). For vxlan/ipv4 it works;

```
ip link add vxlan4 type vxlan dstport 4789 dev eth1 ttl 4 external
ip link set dev vxlan4 up
ip route replace 220.0.0.0/24 dev vxlan4 encap ip id 100 dst 192.168.2.221
```

But the same configuration does not work for IPv6;

```
ip -6 link add vxlan6 type vxlan dstport 4789 dev eth1 ttl 4 external
ip link set dev vxlan6 up
ip -6 route replace 3000::/96 dev vxlan6 encap ip6 id 100 dst 1000::1:c0a8:2dd
```

The commands are accepted, but no packets to 3000::/96 are sent (tested with tcpdump).

How to setup tunnel/vxlan using "ip encap" for IPv6 on Linux?

My versions:

```
ip utility, iproute2-5.19.0
Kernel linux-6.0.0
```

I have similar problems with GRE tunnels.

Answer (score 1):

This may have been an [xyproblem](https://xyproblem.info/). What I wanted was a way to tunnel both ipv4 and ipv6 to many destination using only one local tunnel interface. I thought vxlan would be best since it seems to be most used, but I found a way using [ip6tnl](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/05/17/an-introduction-to-linux-virtual-interfaces-tunnels#ip6tnl_tunnel):

```
ip link add ip6tnl6 type ip6tnl external
ip link set up dev ip6tnl6
ip -6 route replace 3000::/96 dev ip6tnl6 encap ip6 dst 1000::1:192.168.2.221
ip route replace 220.0.0.0/24 dev ip6tnl6 encap ip6 dst 1000::1:192.168.2.221
```

With this setup both ipv4 to 220.0.0.0/24 and ipv6 to 3000::/96 will be tunneled to the same ipv6 destination, 1000::1:192.168.2.221. And I can add more routes to other destinations using the same tunnel interface.

If anybody knows why the same commands doesn't work for vxlan I am still interrested though.